# How to change visiblity of the Angular-material2 control?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have many controls on my form. I evaluate some rules for my controls. When the `visiblityExpression` for certain control will be evaluated to false I would like make the control not visible.

`this.formControl` dervies from `AbstractControl`. 
What method I can call to make it not visible to the user?

I wanted to do something like that:
`if(result === false) this.formControl.hide();`

Answer (score 1):

I think [hidden] directive on top of your form with boolean variable `isVisible` should do the trick:

```
[hidden]="formControl.isVisible"
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7ub2fy7CBdBA46i4qkvv?p=preview) Example with hiding textboxes. The same can be apply for whole control. Personally I think it is better to remove control from DOM with ***ngIf** than just hide it.

Comment: Can I add directive from outside of html template and any other component files? I want to be able to hide it just having a reference to the control. For Instance `this.formControl.disable()` disables the control. My example is far more compund than I present it here on SO.... there are reasons.

Comment: Unfortunetly this is not that straight forward but... You can try to create communication service for your component. Place [hidden] with boolean variable on top of your form tag and from the service invoke function with will call for example disable() function in commponent where you have form control. Disable function after invoke will change variable true/false and in the same way hide/show form. You can register service method with Observable and than listen for any status changes in component with form control.